# Is it possible to downgrade a managed package?

Tags: managed-package, package, support

Have any of you gurus ever successfully *downgraded* a managed package?

I'm aware that officially, you are [not able to downgrade to earlier versions](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004987&language=en_US). And I appreciate many component types are one-way in nature, though there was a [component deprecation pilot](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/12577/320) for a time.

That said, if you can uninstall all deployments from all orgs of a particular package version and Salesforce will revert it from `Release` to `Beta` status without too much trouble. I'm wondering if there is any anecdotal info to be had here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, sometimes, but it's non-trivial. You need to submit a case and work closely with partner support and your account team.

Answer (score 1):

From Salesforce help article:

**Can I roll back a package to a previously installed version?**

**Knowledge Article Number**    000213722

**Description**

Currently we cannot roll back or downgrade a package to the previously installed version in any type of org (sandbox or production).

**Resolution**

The only workaround is to uninstall the package, export the package data, re-install the desired version, and then import any data back into the org. See page 104 of the packaging guide for additional information around 'Uninstalling a package' : ISVforce .

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213722&type=1

Answer (score 0):

You cannot downgrade a package that has been already installed to an earlier version. You can only either upgrade or uninstall and reinstall the desired version.

Comment: Do you have any references to back up your claim?

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you need to raise a case with Salesforce Support,  according to their help article [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381570&type=1)

```
 Support can assist you with a revert back to Beta. To do so, please log a case in the Partner Community with the following acknowledgements/details:


- Developer Org Id for the package in question.

- All Package ID (033xxxxxxxxxxxx).

- What version(s) do you want reverted to beta (please include version # and it's 04txxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Id).

- Confirmation that you understand all subsequent versions will be also forced to beta.

- Are there any patch orgs created for the package version(s) being reverted? If any exist, please provide their Org Id(s) and permission to delete them (required to revert to beta). Be sure to backup any changes made in those patch versions prior to providing permission to delete them. 

- Make sure the required (and subsequent) version(s) are not currently installed in any org. If they are, they will have to be uninstalled for us to revert back to beta (required to revert to beta).

- You are aware the new version will need to go through security review (only for Aloha-approved / AppExchange packages that have already passed).

- You may need to pay the review fee (only for Aloha-approved / AppExchange packages that have already paid).
```